# vue.js Change the font for the whole website

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a question.
I am currently trying to change the Font of the hole application. I am managing to change the Font only for the current page that the button is (the button that is for changing the font). Whenever I go to the other pages, the Font is back to normal.

I am wondering if I can make it with a global variable and how can I do that, or how otherwise I can do that if not with a global variable?

Comment: You set the font through the `font-family` css statement, so I am assuming that your application either sets it somewhere else, or that it is never set anywhere and uses the default font. Further debug steps are to open the developer console and inspecting the computed/applied styling for something that does not have the desired font. Look for the `font-family` and go from there. If something is applied, you can see which selectors are being used. If nothing is applied, you can quickly see this as well.

Comment: you can use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to manage state changes in your spa. also, persist the changes in state with `localStorage` or with a database via an api, according to your requirement.

Comment: I am not talking for Spa because I am working on a multiple pages and I don't use the database.